# MACHTYPE environment variable on ARM

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, zsh, environment-variables

I am on an M3 Pro, MacOS 14.2. When I try `echo $MACHTYPE` (in a default `-zsh` shell) the output is `x86_64`, whereas [uname](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uname.1.html) `-mp` returns `arm64 arm`. [Zsh docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) say that `MACHTYPE` should be "the machine type (microprocessor class or machine model), as determined at compile time." Why is my compile time machine type set to `x86_64`? I am not running Terminal with Rosetta. Perhaps a more robust question, what is the intended usage of the `MACHTYPE` shell parameter on ARM-based MacOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've highlighted the important part in the text you took from the ZSH documentation:

> the machine type (microprocessor class or machine model), **as determined at compile time**.

This means that Apple compiled `zsh` on an Intel machine, for both x64 and arm64. It also means that the practical use of `MACHTYPE` is rather limited and (if you need to know the architecture at runtime) `uname -m` is the more accurate option.

PS: In `bash`, `MACHTYPE` is defined as "describes the system             type on which bash is executing". This explains why in `/bin/bash`, I get `arm64-apple-darwin23`, in Homebrew `bash` it's `aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0`, and in Homebrew `zsh` it's `arm`. It also means that you need to check the shell used when following examples found online. If you need the `MACHTYPE` equivalent of `bash` in `zsh`, use `CPUTYPE` ("The machine type (microprocessor class or machine model), as determined at run time.").

Comment: do `arm64-apple-darwin23` and `aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0.` refer to the same compile time machine type? also (perhaps not really a stackexchange appropriate question), why would Apple compile `zsh` on an old architecture? a more comfortable/robust ecosystem for their in-house developers perhaps? i suppose i am particularly confused about the use of `x86_64` in light of `bash` compiling fine on `arm64`.

Comment: @shea Xcode cross-compilation works both ways, it doesn’t matter on which hardware Apple runs this. It could also be just a bug in the way `zsh` sets MACHTYPE.

Comment: @shea You can see from the text quoted from the `bash` manpage, in `bash` the variable MACHTYPE is set at **execution** time.  Not at compile time.

Comment: @MarcWilson that's an intriguing difference! i wonder if `zsh` changed MACHTYPE's behavior in comparison to `bash` due to the execution time machine type already being in `uname -m`?

Comment: There's no standard for what that variable is supposed to represent, while `uname -m` is [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html).